# Laravel saving related data before parent save

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have a form in my Laravel app where a user can create a post, this post has a relationship from the posts table to the images table, where are post has  a 1:n relationship with images.

My problem is I cannot figure a logical way to save the images to the database, the images are uploaded via ajax, so need to be saved before the user has completed the full post form. How can I save the ID of the post with the images in the images table, before the post has actually been saved?

Comment: Are you uploading the images before saving the full post? Maybe you want to assing a temporal reference id (and store it in session), so that when you save the post, can retrieve the images and associate them correctly.

Comment: Thanks, for the idea, decided to assign the key a NULL value until the form is saved, and save the ID to all the null images in that table.

Comment: Be careful with concurrence, if two or more users upload images at the same time, all the images will be associated to the first that submit the form. I think it's better to use a temporal key stored in session.

Comment: This use case should not happed, the system is an internal CMS, that one person and one person only will have access too, there should only every be one save happening at anyone time, might be worth thinking about further though thanks.

Comment: like said be careful with null, take this case someone start uploading images but close the page before save